# Taking a photo and trying to dismiss the preview in didFinishPickingMediaWIthInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to dismiss the preview after a photo is taken on my app. I just want to press the shutter button and then pop back to the `UIViewController` that presented the `UIImagePickerController` without showing the image preview and "Retake" and "Use Photo" buttons. I am using this code:

```
- (IBAction)pushTakePhoto:(id)sender {

    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;



    UIImage *catEars = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cameraoverlay"];//320*101
    UIImageView *overlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:catEars];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.earsX = screenRect.size.width/2-overlayImageView.frame.size.width/2;
    self.earsY = 120;
    self.earsWidth = overlayImageView.frame.size.width;
    self.earsHeight = overlayImageView.frame.size.height;

    //bar size is 40 at the top and the bottom one is 101


    overlayImageView.frame=CGRectMake(self.earsX, self.earsY, self.earsWidth, self.earsHeight);
    [self.picker setCameraOverlayView:overlayImageView];

    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

and in `didFinishPickingMediaWIthInfo` I am trying to use `[self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` However it is having no affect. Could anyone give me some pointers please on how to go about this?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Tried that and no luck. Wouldn't that in theory dismiss the view controller containing the UIImagePickerController and not the UIImagePickerController itself?

Comment: Do you have `- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker` implemented? Besides picker is passed to delegate method, there is no need to store property for that.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in viewDidLoad

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadPhotoCaptured) name:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" object:nil];
```

Then implement this method

Try

```
- (void)loadPhotoCaptured
{
   UIImage *img = [[[self allImageViewsSubViews:[[[picker viewControllers]firstObject] view]] lastObject] image];
    if (img)
    {
        [self imagePickerController:nil didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:img forKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
    }
    else
    {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}                                                                                                                                                   

 - (NSMutableArray*)allImageViewsSubViews:(UIView *)view
{
    NSMutableArray *arrImageViews=[NSMutableArray array];
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        [arrImageViews addObject:view];
    }
    else
    {
        for (UIView *subview in [view subviews])
        {
            [arrImageViews addObjectsFromArray:[self allImageViewsSubViews:subview]];
        }
    }
    return arrImageViews;
}
```

Comment: This dismisses the controller but won't call - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info so will be unable to save the photo.

Comment: I like how you use private notification and suggest it to use to others.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have implemented the method with exact signature: `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`?
Because both `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and `[self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` should dismiss picker controller in your case.

Comment: Are you sure that this method is called?

Comment: Actually it's not called until "Use Photo" is pressed..maybe I need to somehow tell the app to auto use the photo without pressing "Use Photo" and the method will be called and it will dismiss..

Comment: So that's the point. The whole idea of using UIImagePickerController that the user picks/shots the photo and confirms by pressing "Use Photo". If you would like to handle it another way, I would suggest you implement Photo Controller yourself or choose one from GitHub's implementations.

Comment: Oh, just fixed it. had to set self.picker.showsCameraControls=NO; And then place a UIButton into the custom UIImagePickerController that calls [self.picker takePicture];

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post this incase someone else finds it useful. `[self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` does work and has to be placed in `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`, however if you are using the default camera controls it will always display "Retake" and "Use Photo" before calling - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info. The way to get around it is to set `self.picker.showsCameraControls=NO;` and include a `UIButton` in the `cameraOverlayView` that calls `[self.picker takePicture]`. Works now. Thanks guys